# Higher order numerical derivative Python

Tags: python, numpy

I try to implement a higher order numerical derivative using recursion.
I don't see what is wrong with my code.

To clarify, i want to compute `dy^n/dx^n`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def derivative(x,y,n):
    if(n==1):
        return np.gradient(y,x)
    else:
        return derivative(x,y,n-1)

a=0
b=10
N_points=10000

x=np.linspace(a,b,N_points)
y=np.cos(x)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,label="f(x)")
for n in range(1,8):
    plt.plot(x,derivative(x,y,n),label="fprime(x)")
plt.legend()
plt.title("function and derivative")
```

I improved my code to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def derivative(x,y,n):
    if(n==1):
        return np.gradient(y,x)
    else:
        return np.gradient(derivative(x,y,n-1),x)

a=0
b=10
N_points=10000

x=np.linspace(a,b,N_points, dtype=float)
y=np.cos(x, dtype=float)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,label="f(x)")

n_max=7
for n in range(1,n_max):
    yprime=derivative(x,y,n)
    yprime[0:n]=yprime[n]
    yprime[-n:]=yprime[-n-1]

    plt.plot(x,yprime,label=f"fprime{n}(x)")


plt.legend()
plt.title("function and derivative")
```

Now, for `n_max<=5` everything looks like it should do. But for `n_max` greater than that, the derivatives begin to look very noisy. What is happening? And could it be a problem with data types?

[image: First 4 derivatives look fine]

[image: After that they look noisy]

Comment: If `derivative(x,y,2)` is just going to return exactly  `derivative(x,y,1)` which is just going to return exactly `np.gradient(y,x)`, then all `derivative` is is a confusing alias for `np.gradient` with an unhelpful extra parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the derivative of y^n with respect to x, this is the code:
(EDIT: added missing `x`)

```
def derivative(x,y,n):
    if(n==1):
        return np.gradient(y,x)
    else:
        return np.gradient(derivative(x,y,n-1),x)
```

Comment: Sorry! I misinterpreted the question, just edited now. See if that is what you wanted

Comment: Now it's fine. I just have to remove the large values at the start and end of the derivative.

Comment: You can do it using np.clip

Comment: Thanks. The bigger problem now are strange (numerical) errors. See above.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem has to do with the classic problem of "small difference of large numbers" and finite precision floating point math.

Analytic formulas for high order derivatives may still have the "small difference of large numbers" problem; it's just hard, frankly.

The 8th derivative of sin(x) will be challenging to compute numerically with high accuracy ... even though the 8th derivative of sin(x) is, of course, sin(x).

A somewhat more difficult example would be the computation of high order derivatives of f(x)/g(x), when both f(x) and g(x) are known functions.  Mathematically, the problem is well posed, but given the chain rule for derivatives of ratios, the problem will inevitably become challenging.

If the functions f(x) and g(x) are not known analytically, but only numerically, and even if its composition h(x) = f(x)/g(x) was known, it is quite simply, challenging to accurately compute high order derivatives.